# OOP demonstration in C++17 using a Pokémon

Tags: c++, object-oriented, random, c++17, pokemon

I want to showcase with as minimal code as possible the basic Object-oriented programming (OOP) principles of Polymorphism, Inheritance, and Encapsulation. I know there are many more principles than just these 3 and even different types of the 3 I've mentioned there. I attempted to implement them all below. I think using Pokémon as an example is a good way to show this, so I've used [Castform](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Castform_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) as my buddy of choice for these examples.

If you believe showcasing more than just Polymorphism, Inheritance, and Encapsulation to evaluate a developers understanding of OOP, please provide comments around this and which additional key principles I should add to my Pokémon example.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

class Pokemon
{
    protected:
        int m_dex_num;
        float m_catch_rate;
        std::string m_type;
    public:
        Pokemon(int dex_num, int catch_rate, std::string type)
            : m_dex_num(dex_num), m_catch_rate(catch_rate), m_type(type) {}

        int dex_num() const { return m_dex_num; }
        float catch_rate() const { return m_catch_rate; }
        std::string type() const { return m_type; }

        virtual bool attempt_catch() = 0;
};

class Castform : public Pokemon
{
    private:
        std::string m_forms[3] = { "sunny", "rainy", "snowy" };
    public:
        Castform() : Pokemon(351, 11.9, "normal") {}

        bool attempt_catch() {
            srand(time(NULL));
            return (rand() % 100) < m_catch_rate;
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto wild_castform = Castform();

    std::cout << "Wild Castform appeared!\n";
    std::cout << "Dex number " << wild_castform.dex_num() << '\n';
    std::cout << "It's a " << wild_castform.type() << " type\n";

    for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Catch attempt resulted in " << wild_castform.attempt_catch() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: c++]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It looks like all the `Pokemon` member variables should be private, not public.
- The `Pokemon` constructor takes `catch_rate` as an `int`, where it should be a float.
- The `Pokemon` constructor could `std::move` the string argument into `m_type`.
- `Pokemon::type()` could return by `const&` to avoid an unnecessary copy.
- `Castform::m_forms` is not used anywhere, but should probably also be `static` and `const`.
- When overriding a virtual function, we should always use the `override` keyword (and arguably also the `virtual` keyword):

  ```
  virtual bool attempt_catch() override { ... }
  ```
- Use the C++11 `<random>` functionality, not `rand()`.

---

Run-time polymorphism with virtual functions in C++ is driven by a need to treat objects of different types with the same interface. Unfortunately, this example lacks the motivation for it:

- Currently the `attempt_catch()` function could be implemented in the `Pokemon` base-class with no problem.
- There is no example of differing behavior (i.e. there should be a second pokemon type implementing a different `attempt_catch()` function). Maybe an attack function would work better?
- There is no demonstration of using the different types through the same interface. In C++ this usually boils down to storing different types in the same container (e.g. iterating a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pokemon>>` and calling the virtual function). However, it might be simpler to pass two different pokemon types to a function taking a `Pokemon` reference:

  ```
  void throw_pokeball(Pokemon const& target) { target.attempt_catch() } // or something
  ```

---

Depending on what this is actually for, I'd suggest approaching things in a "problem `->` solution" way, both in terms of what the code does (see above), but also in terms of language development and why these features exist. i.e.

- "Here's what programmers used to have to do without this language feature [...]. It sucks because [...]"
- "This language feature allows us to do [...] safely and easily because [...]".

---

Note that there are many different types of both static and dynamic polymorphism in C++ (e.g. function overloading, implicit conversions, function objects, template parameters (traits, tags, etc.)), not just inheritance and virtual functions.

Comment: Using `std::move` on the string argument into `m_type` in the Pokemon ctor would avoid another unnecessary string copy correct?